# Write program to check if an integer is divisible by 2, 3 and 5

Tags: homework, mathematica-online

> Write a program to check if an integer is divisible by either 2, 3 or 5. If an integer is divisible more than one of these numbers it should also show all of them.

For example:

- 8 is divisible by only 2
- 10 is divisible by 2 and 5
- 30 is divisible by 2, 3 and 5

Comment: Check out [`Divisors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisors.html) and [`Divisible`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Divisible.html?q=Divisible).

Comment: If an number is divisible by "2, 3 &5", then it is divisible by all three of them, and therefore it is divisible by more than one.  Perhaps you meant "or", not "&"?  The example, while a true statement, seems pointless, since it does not indicate what the output should be in each case.

Comment: What output is specified for inputs divisible by none of 2, 3, 5?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a "code my homework" site.

Answer (score 10):

```
f[x_]:=Intersection[Divisors[x],{2,3,5}]

f[30]
```

> {2, 3, 5}

```
f[100]
```

> {2, 5}

```
f[27]
```

> {3}

---

More general:

```
g[x_, divisors_List]:=Intersection[Divisors[x],divisors]

g[25, {2, 3, 5}]
```

> {5}

Answer (score 2):

```
If[1!=GCD[n, 2 3 5],FactorInteger[GCD[n, 2 3 5]][[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: Why the `If`?  There's no specification what to output for relatively prime inputs.  Also, if we're golfing ... `If[1!=#,FactorInteger[#][[All, 1]]]&@GCD[n, 30]`.

Comment: @EricTowers, with relatively prime inputs, nothing is output.

Comment: I see no specification for that conclusion.  I only see specification for divisible inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that you can use the rightmost digit for 2 and 5 - eg: [2,4,6,8,0] for 2 amd [0,5] for 5.

With 3 this gets a little bit lengthy.  A different approach is to sum all the digits repeaatdly until the final 1 digit number is that of 0, 3, 6, 9.  eg: 342 is 3+4+2 = 9 so it's divisible by 3.

Code left for reader but on smaller processors without a divide op these can drastically speed up the checks.

Comment: I actually think this is a good point, but an answer without code, is not an answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is not faster, in fact it's about 2 times slower than the most upvoted answer.

Comment: As I said it depends on the processor.

Comment: Feyre - Not high enough level yet to post as a comment.

Comment: I would upvote this as an answer if you fix the typos and add Mma code to carry out the checks you suggest. Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange.